# Datepicker events handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have got this addon to my datepicker but I dont want it to give me an alertbox.
I want it to show a div under the datepicker with the event on that day.

I don't know how to change the if (event) to a `<div>` instead of an alert.

```
$(function(){
    var events = [ 
        { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("09/13/2011") }, 
        { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("09/25/2011") }, 
        { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("09/01/2011") }
    ];
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var result = [true, '', null];
            var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
                return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
            });

            if (matching.length) {
                result = [true, 'highlight', null];
            }
            return result;
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

            while (i < events.length && !event) {
                date = events[i].Date;

                if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                    event = events[i];
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (event) {
                alert(event.Title);
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to a `<div>` instead of an alert"? Do you want to update a `<div>` to hold the selected value?

Comment: I dont want it to show an alert when i click the event date, i want the click to show a div with the event text in it, below the datepicker.

Comment: @muistooshort i believe he just wants to really show the events for the chosen date, in a div, instead of having the alert(event.Title) there.

Answer (score 2):

well, i don't know your markup (html)
but here is how you can do it then...

instead of `alert(event.Title);` try this:

```
var eventContainer = ($('#eventContainer').length) ? $('#eventContainer').empty() : $('<div id="eventContainer"></div>');
var eventItem = $('<div/>');
eventItem.text(event.Title);
eventContainer.append(eventItem);
$("#datepicker").after(eventContainer);
```

**edit**
I added the code to a jsFiddle so you can test around with it yourself
http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TgZQJ/11/

Comment: sry that didnt work :(
my markup looks like this:
<div id="column">
<p class="titel">Kalender</p>
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker"></div>
</div>

Comment: i edited my answer, changed the script a bit, now it seems to work, try it out with your markup on the jsFiddle link i gave you